# Logistic regression using Flux.jl

Tags: machine-learning, julia, logistic-regression, flux-machine-learning

I have a dataset consisting of student marks in 2 subjects and the result if the student is admitted in college or not. I need to perform a logistic regression on the data and find the optimum parameter θ to minimize the loss and predict the results for the test data. I am not trying to build any complex non linear network here.

The data looks like this
[image]

I have the loss function defined for logistic regression like this which works fine

```
predict(X) = sigmoid(X*θ)
loss(X,y) = (1 / length(y)) * sum(-y .* log.(predict(X)) .- (1 - y) .* log.(1 - predict(X)))
```

I need to minimize this loss function and find the optimum θ. I want to do it with Flux.jl or any other library which makes it even easier.
I tried using Flux.jl after reading the examples but not able to minimize the cost.

My code snippet:

```
function update!(ps, η = .1)
  for w in ps
    w.data .-= w.grad .* η
    print(w.data)
    w.grad .= 0
  end
end

for i = 1:400
  back!(L)
  update!((θ, b))
  @show L
end
```

Comment: If you provide a simple reproducible example then people will be able to help you a lot more easily.

Comment: @niczky12 Isn't the example I gave simple enough? Anyway I have added rest of the code for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either GLM.jl (simpler) or Flux.jl (more involved but more powerful in general).
In the code I generate the data so that you can check if the result is correct. Additionally I have a binary response variable - if you have other encoding of target variable you might need to change the code a bit.

Here is the code to run (you can tweak the parameters to increase the convergence speed - I chose ones that are safe):

```
using GLM, DataFrames, Flux.Tracker

srand(1)
n = 10000
df = DataFrame(s1=rand(n), s2=rand(n))
df[:y] = rand(n) .< 1 ./ (1 .+ exp.(-(1 .+ 2 .* df[1] .+ 0.5 .* df[2])))
model = glm(@formula(y~s1+s2), df, Binomial(), LogitLink())

x = Matrix(df[1:2])
y = df[3]
W = param(rand(2,1))
b = param(rand(1))
predict(x) = 1.0 ./ (1.0+exp.(-x*W .- b))
loss(x,y) = -sum(log.(predict(x[y,:]))) - sum(log.(1 - predict(x[.!y,:])))

function update!(ps, η = .0001)
  for w in ps
    w.data .-= w.grad .* η
    w.grad .= 0
  end
end

i = 1
while true
  back!(loss(x,y))
  max(maximum(abs.(W.grad)), abs(b.grad[1])) > 0.001 || break
  update!((W, b))
  i += 1
end
```

And here are the results:

```
julia> model # GLM result
StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.GeneralizedLinearModel{GLM.GlmResp{Array{Float64,1},Distributions.Binomial{Float64},GLM.LogitLink},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

Formula: y ~ 1 + s1 + s2

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std.Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.910347 0.0789283 11.5338   <1e-30
s1            2.18707  0.123487 17.7109   <1e-69
s2           0.556293  0.115052 4.83513    <1e-5


julia> (b, W, i) # Flux result with number of iterations needed to converge
(param([0.910362]), param([2.18705; 0.556278]), 1946)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this helpful example. However, it does not seem to run with my setup (Julia 1.1, Flux 0.7.1.), since the 1+ and 1- operations in the predict and loss function is not broadcast over the TrackedArray objects. Fortunately the fix is simple (note the dots!):

```
predict(x) = 1.0 ./ (1.0 .+ exp.(-x*W .- b))
loss(x,y) = -sum(log.(predict(x[y,:]))) - sum(log.(1 .- predict(x[.!y,:])))
```